# 3/2024 $sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full is missing dependences for ubuntu is 20.04.6 LTS tried apt-get update

Tags: ros-noetic, desktop-full

My ubuntu is 20.04.6 LTS, so I picked the ROS Noetic Ninjemys

The result of `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full` is missing dependences: ros-noetic-desktop, ros-noetic-perceptions, ros-noetic-simulations, and ros-noetic-urdf-sim-tutorial

By installing each of the ros-noetic-desktop, ros-noetic-perceptions, ros-noetic-simulations, and ros-noetic-urdf-sim-tutorial, there are many packages to install too.

I wonder if there is a simple way to install all at once for ROS Noetic Ninjemys directly.

After I run

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

it doesn't show anything. After I run

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

it shows OK. After `sudo apt update`, it shows

```
hit:1.. 
hit:2.., 
Get:3..
Hit:4..
Get:5.., 
Get:6.., 
Fetched.. 
Reading package done, 
Building dependence tree done, 
reading state info 
Done
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Truong Mai. Did you follow along with the instructions on [this page](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu)? I'm wondering if you may have accidentally skipped a step in setting up the sources or updating apt.

Comment: Hello Chuck, thank you for responding to my question very quick. I used the instruction on "this page." I ran again all the steps, but I still had the same issue. Have a good day, Chuck.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full output from the commands in your comments. Then also please show 'apt-cache policy PACKAGE-NAME' for any package that you're using trouble with

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution from this link. It works
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install ros-noetic-desktop-full

https://vnav.mit.edu/labs/lab2/ros.html

Comment: If using aptitude fixed it for you, you likely had a number of broken, misconfigured or conflicting packages already on your system that needed to be resolved. I'm the future please make sure to include the full console output of your attempts and you can get help resolving the underlying issue. The main installation instructions are tested and validated regularly.